# Does changing the y-axis and x-axis label changes anything in the image using imshow?

Tags: matplotlib

[image]I want to show values as pixels. But my x-axis and y-axis show different range.I don't know what these values are telling us. But I read somewhere that we have to read the values as intensity values. They will not be visualized on the axis. Then what these axis are telling us? Secondly if I use xticks and yticks to label x and y axis does it has any effect on the image? Does it flip anything in the image?

```
`# a is an array of shape(500,2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,2))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,500))
plt.imshow(a,aspect='auto',cmap=plt.cm.gray)`
```

Comment: By default, the axis ticks denote the positions (centers) of the pixels. The first pixel is at (0,0).

Comment: I have updated my question with a figure. If the ticks show center of the pixels.  How can I explain the value -0.25 or 0.75 on x-axis? Does does it tell us in above figure?

Comment: You have 2 pixels in horizontal direction. The first pixel center is at 0.00, the second at 1.00. Since a pixel is 1 unit large, the first pixel ranges from -0.5 to 0.5, the second pixel from 0.5 to 1.5.

Comment: If I explain it w.r.t y axis. Can I say that pixel 400 on y-axis is centered at 0 and 1?

Comment: There are two pixels with y=400, one at 0 and one at 1.